# How can I read cloudwatch logs using `aws-sdk`in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I read cloudwatch logs using `aws-sdk`in nodejs?

I don't know how to init my config, where can I find any keys/endpoints to my cloudwatch ?

Can someone provide me some example?

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'; 
const cwInstance = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({
  .....?
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'; 

const cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({apiVersion: '2014-03-28'});
const params = {
  logGroupName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  logStreamName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  endTime: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  limit: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  nextToken: 'STRING_VALUE',
  startFromHead: true || false,
  startTime: 'NUMBER_VALUE'
};
cloudwatchlogs.getLogEvents(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

For the more information check [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#getLogEvents-property)

Answer (score 3):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
const cloudWatchLogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({apiVersion: '2014-03-28'});

const timestamp = new Date();
const endtTime = timestamp.getTime();
const params = {
    endTime: endtTime,
    filterPattern: `"${stringToSearch}"`,
    startTime: new Date (endtTime - 5 * 60 * 60* 24 * 1000).getTime(), // Last 5 days
    logGroupName: 'myLogGroup',
    limit : 10
};

const events = await cloudWatchLogs.filterLogEvents(params).promise();
console.log(`successfully queryCloudWatchLogs ${stringToSearch} results: ${JSON.stringify(events)}`);
const results = events.events.map(e => e.message)
console.log(`successfully queryCloudWatchLogs ${stringToSearch} results (${results.length}): ${JSON.stringify(results)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function queryCloudWatch(queryRequest: StartQueryRequest): Promise<GetQueryResultsResponse> {
    const queryResponse: StartQueryResponse = await cloudwatchLogs.startQuery(queryRequest).promise()

    if (!queryResponse.queryId) return {}

    let response: GetQueryResultsResponse | undefined = undefined

    while (!response || response.status === 'Running') {
        response = await cloudwatchLogs.getQueryResults({
            "queryId": queryResponse.queryId
        }).promise()
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the following to write the logs on cloudWatch, you can do the same for read.

**Here are the codes (service) that I created for AWS Cloudwatch:**

```
// logger.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import Config from '../../shared/config/app.config-setting';
const config = Config() as Record<string, any>;

@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
 private cloudWatchLogs: AWS.CloudWatchLogs;

 constructor() {
  this.cloudWatchLogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({
   region: YOUR_AWS_REGION,
   accessKeyId: YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
   secretAccessKey: YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  });
 }


// AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME: 'API-LOG-GROUP-DEV'
// AWS_LOG_GROUP_STREAM_NAME: 'API-LOG-GROUP-STREAM-DEV'

 /** Check if log group exist */
 async isLogGroupExist(logGroupName) {
  const logGroupResult: any = await this.cloudWatchLogs
   .describeLogGroups({ logGroupNamePrefix: logGroupName })
   .promise();
  return logGroupResult?.logGroups?.length > 0;
 }

 /** Check if log group stream exist */
 async isLogGroupStreamExist(logGroupName, logStreamName) {
  const logGroupStreams: any = await this.cloudWatchLogs
   .describeLogStreams({
    logGroupName,
    logStreamNamePrefix: logStreamName,
   })
   .promise();
  return logGroupStreams?.logStreams?.length > 0;
 }

 async createLogGroup(logGroupName: string) {
  try {
   await this.cloudWatchLogs.createLogGroup({ logGroupName }).promise();
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(`Error while creating log group ${error?.message}`);
   return;
  }
 }

 async createLogStream(logGroupName: string, logStreamName: string) {
  try {
   await this.cloudWatchLogs.createLogStream({ logGroupName, logStreamName }).promise();
  } catch (error) {
   console.log('createdLogStream error :', error.message);
   return;
  }
 }

 async handleAWSLogs() {

  const isLogGroupExist = await this.isLogGroupExist(config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME);

  if (!isLogGroupExist) {
   console.log(`Creating cloud watch log group :${config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME}`);

   await this.createLogGroup(config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME);

   console.log(`Creating cloud watch log group stream :${config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME}`);

   await this.createLogStream(config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME, config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_STREAM_NAME);

  } else {

   const isLogStreamExist = await this.isLogGroupStreamExist(
    config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME,
    config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_STREAM_NAME,
   );

   if (!isLogStreamExist) {
    console.log(`Creating cloud watch log group stream :${config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME}`);

    await this.createLogStream(config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME, config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_STREAM_NAME);

   }
  }
 }

 async log(message: any) {
  try {
    const logGroupName = config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_NAME;
    const logStreamName = config.AWS_LOG_GROUP_STREAM_NAME;

    /** You need to call only as per requirement, No need to call this in each log  */

   this.handleAWSLogs();

    const params = {
     logGroupName,
     logStreamName,
     logEvents: [
      {
       message,
       timestamp: Date.now(),
      },
     ],
    };
    this.cloudWatchLogs.putLogEvents(params).promise();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
   console.log('Error in LoggerService:', error);
  }
 }
}
```

**How to use this service:**

```
import { LoggerService } from '../../shared/aws/logger';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

 constructor(
  private readonly logger: LoggerService
 ) {}

 async someMethod(): Promise<any> {
    this.logger.log(`My Logs ${JSON.stringify({message: "new Message"})}`);
 }

}
```

See the logs on cloudWatch logs:

[image]